# Shifting and Copying std::vector elements

Tags: arrays, vector, position, element, shift

I have an array of elements which I want to copy into another array and shift it by 1 position. So something like that:

```
void Blubb(){

    std::vector<double> array1(n);
    std::vector<double> array2(n+1);

    while(//a condition){
    //do some stuff

        for(int i = 0; i < (n+1); i ++){

            array1[i] = array2[i+1];

        }

        //do some more stuff
    }
}
```

The first element in array2 is intentionally not part of array1.

Is there any "easy" way to do that? Does the container class already provide something similar? Or are there any other classes I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the template argument for std::vector. Anyway, try something like:

```
std::vector<int> array2(n+1);
std::vector<int> array1(array2.begin()+1, array2.end());
```

Comment: I propably should have added, that I need that to happen more than once. It is actually part of an iterative calculation. Imagine there is a loop around the for loop ;)

Comment: In this case use assign: array1.assign(array2.begin()+1, array2.end()).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need a template argument: replace all occurrences of `std::vector` with `std::vector<int>`, replacing `int` with whichever type you're using.
First copy the vector:

```
std::vector<int> array2(n+1);
// fill the vector
std::vector<int> array1(array2);
```

(Note that array2 has to be declared first.)

Secondly, delete the first element:

```
array1.erase(array1.begin());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just edited it. Is it possible to do that kind outside the declaration? And indeed I forgot the argument

Comment: If you're asking whether or not it is possible to remove the first element of the vector outside of the declaration, yes.